# Registros duplicados mysql

Tags: mysql

Estoy intentando mostrar los codigos duplicados en una consulta mysql.

Lo estoy haciendo con este codigo:

```
SELECT `id`, `idarticulo`, `talla`, `color`, count(*) FROM `CodigosEan` GROUP BY `idarticulo`, `talla`, `color` HAVING count(*) > 1
```

El problema es que si hay duplicados los agrupa y no veo cuales son. Necesitaría saber los id de todos afectados ( o agrupados ) ¿Hay alguna forma de saberlo?

Comment: podrias agregar un ejemplo?

Comment: ¿Qué consideras un duplicado? ¿Pueden 2 registros tener el mismo `idarticulo`, o es esa columna la clave primaria?  Hay que entender claramente lo que viene siendo un duplicado. Lo ideal es que des ejemplos de datos para ilustrar lo que tienes y lo que deseas.

Comment: Duplicado seria que tengan el mismo id de articulo, la misma talla y el mismo color @sstan

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Con Inner Join (uniendo la tabla codigosean con el resultado de tu consulta de duplicados)

```
SELECT tc.id, tc.idarticulo, tc.talla, tc.color
  FROM CodigosEan tc 
     INNER JOIN
       ( SELECT  idarticulo, talla, color, count(*) 
          FROM  CodigosEan 
          GROUP BY idarticulo, talla, color 
            HAVING count(*) > 1 
        ) t2
     ON tc.idarticulo = t2.idarticulo and
        tc.talla = t2.talla and 
        tc.color = t2.color
```

Comment: Funcionaaaa!!! Mil graciaas

Comment: Le había dado, pero según parece demasiado rápido y no lo había guardado  @sstan

Answer (score 0):

estas realizando el **`count(*)`** es decir **GLOBAL**, debes de agregar la variables que quieres contar cuando se cumpla una agrupacion

```
SELECT count(idarticulo) as cantidad_repetidos, 
        idarticulo,
        talla, 
        color  
  FROM codigosean 
 GROUP BY idarticulo
HAVING cantidad_repetidos > 1;
```